# How can I change colors of the word?

Tags: discussion, support

Let’s say, I want to write a question and then I write a word with blue color or red color or any color because I saw this site:

[What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/)

And I want to know if it is possible to write in any color any word on IPhone 6? Because, I’m planning to improve in a proper manner my posts in better than ever. Can you please tell me how to write for example in: blue, red, green etc...? I’m trying to do as others do, but it does not work to me. Can you tell me how each code means? And what does it do?  And, seriously, I don’t understand what does it do some codes.

Comment: You can check Stack Exchange's limited set of [supported HTML tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/). I do not see color or CSS being supported. The colors you are referring to are most likely dictated by the SE site's style sheet. A word of advice: focus on content and let SE handle the presentation.

Comment: @III-AK-III Maybe You haven’t checked the site I posted?

Comment: The site you posted is the site that I provided to you in your [previous question](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3202/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blue font in [the linked post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) are caused by links.  They're a different color on meta.

There's no (desirable) way to change the font color of certain words.  A proposal was declined on meta.SE: [Having font color option in Stack Overflow question editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115455/351283)

There's workarounds like including images (where you can color things however you like), or it would be possible to write a local script, to add color locally.

(*Side note*: Sites with MathJax (not Islam.SE) can use color in math mode.)

There's a help page on [formatting](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

## It *might*

### be *worthwhile*

#### having *a*

**play *around***

with *the*

1. current

   - <kbd>capabilities</kbd>

   2.

   - `see`

     - [what](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/what)

       - > they

         - <s>can</s><sup>and can't</sup>

           - > do.

It's also possible to write in a different font using Unicode:

## '

## '

These can be generated using online apps such as: https://lingojam.com/FancyTextGenerator or http://qaz.wtf/u/convert.cgi  This is not such a great idea though, since it's not possible to search.